# Failure to create a database using Couchbase Lite

Tags: database, swift, couchbase-lite

In my app I am using an couchbase lite database, but I am failure to create an database:

Here is my code in `AppDelegate.swift`

```
import UIKit

private let DatabaseName = "couchbase-swift"

@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate 
{

     var window: UIWindow?
     var viewC : ViewController!
    
    let database: CBLDatabase!
    
    override init() {
        do{
            database = try(CBLManager.sharedInstance().databaseNamed(DatabaseName))
        }
        catch _ {
            database = nil
        }
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
    {
        
        
        if database == nil {
            print("Unable to initialize Couchbase Lite")
            return false
        }

        //---- Add RootView Controller------
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        
        viewC = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)
        
        window?.rootViewController = viewC
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        
        return true
    }
}
```

I got nill database with WARNING:

> Upgrade skipped: Database upgrading class is not present.
>
> *** ASSERTION FAILED: CBLManager.storageType is 'SQLite' but no CBL_SQLiteStorage class found

Please tell me that what was wrong in my code. Why do I get failure to create a database?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for, this is an example where you create a new Couchbase lite manager instance, create a new CouchbaseLite Database instance and then create a new document, insert it and also retrieve it

```
  var properties = [
    "name": "mirco",
    "email": "mirco.zeiss@gmail.com",
    "repo": "swift-couchbaselite-cheatsheet"
]


 //creating a couchbase manager
 let manager = CBLManager.sharedInstance()

 {

        NSLog("creating the database")
        let db = try manager.databaseNamed("mydb")

        NSLog("Creating the document")
        //we then create a document to store the properties
        let doc = db.createDocument()

        do {
            try doc.putProperties(properties)
            NSLog("The Document was updated with properties")

            print(properties)

        } catch {

            NSLog("Too bad, things be tight")
            print("Oops! the document was not updated")
        }

    }catch {

        print("Oops! the Database was not created")
    }
```

Details can be found here 
https://github.com/mwanjajoel/CouchBaseTesting/tree/master/CouchBaseTesting

I hope this helps you get started with CouchBase Lite

Answer (score 0):

Faced same problem but not for couchbase and solve by adding below flag.
Make sure  -ObjC flag added to your target's Other Linker Flags build setting . Sometimes it may generate above error.

Thanks

Comment: I have added the -ObjC flag in my target's Other Linker Flags buit setting. but it doesn't make any changes. this error is again occured after adding that flag